# Ruby On Rails "Hello World" page doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new in ruby on rails and I have a problem. When I starе server " `rails server` and going to the page 
`www.localhost:3000` 
in my browser everything works fine with ROR default page, but....  after making controller `rails generate controller demo index` 
and going to the page 
`www.localhost:3000/demo/index` , `localhost:3000/demo` - the same
- there is nothing, seems like page doesn't exist, only a blank page. I tried to change index.html.erb code 
`<h1>Hello World</h1>`
- no change. I want to practice with ROR, but can't because of that bug.

Work environment: Windows 7 64-bit

Database: MySQL

Comment: Have you deleted index.html out of your public folder yet?  (See answer below)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a view corresponding to your action.

If your controller is called `Demo` and your action is `index` it should be

```
# app/controllers/demo_controller.rb
class DemoController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

and the view file should be at `app/views/demo/index.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` action is the base action of the controller.  Try just:

```
http://localhost:3000/demo
```

to access the index.

By default routes `/demo/index` is the `show` action with the id of `index`.

Comment: the same as with "/demo/index", i don't know where is the problem, it shows me white page without any error

Comment: In your route table do you have a line like `resources 'demo'`?  Or `match '/demo' => 'demo#index'`.  It's hard to guess without seeing more. :p

Comment: yes, i have "get "demo/index"" , and match '/demo' => 'demo#index'

Answer (score 0):

make sure

views/layout/application.html.erb has **yield** and **index.html.erb** have some text

Answer (score 0):

check your routes.rb

```
root :to => 'demo#index'
```

Go to `http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score 0):

**Uncomment** this line from your config/routes.rb file

```
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

**Remove** index.html file from `public/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete or rename the `index.html` file from public folder.

Then set `root :to => 'demo#index'` at route file.

Then restart the server by using this command. `rails s` by default your server will run at port 3000.

Now simply type `http://localhost:3000/` or `http://localhost:3000/demo/index`

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted

```
app_root
--public
----index.html
```

yet?

Rails will look in the public folder first for a matching file before it will goto build one from your views.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by João there, you will also need a view for that. Additionally, delete `public/index.html` and finally add a route for your controller.

If you had created a scaffold [Rails start guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) you would already have the route there for you.